# Random images don't display on website

Tags: html, css, web, display

I uploaded a website online, and some of the images on of the pages does not display.

I have checked the path multiple times and I copied and pasted the src link, then just changed the name of the file, which was a number. eg: `product1.jpg` then `product2.jpg`, but the image of product 1 would display and not the image of product 2.

Is there anything else I can do to try fix it? Or find where the problem is?

[Here is the product page of the current website.](http://www.hanlerproducts.co.za/products.html)

Comment: If you check your website with a Developer tool (for example push F12 on Chrome) you will see a lot of error related to image loading. There are a lot of response 404 not foud.

Comment: you can see, that your header's pic it's OK, because link is OK: http://www.hanlerproducts.co.za/media/header/header.png, but we can't see any products pics because links are wrong: hanlerproducts.co.za/media/style/products/p1/products6.jpg. Problem: "The requested URL /media/style/products/p1/products6.jpg was not found on this server."

Answer (score 0):

Try using the debugger of the browser

On **Chrome** you can press F12, then go to the Sources section and check (and preview) the files the browser has recieved. If you see both pictures and you can preview them, then it is the HTML/CSS code of the page which, creates the problem. If you don't see them, the problem must be in the paths(check if you're using relative or absolute paths)

On **Firefox** you can press F12 and go to the Debugger section, and from there is is the same process.